# jQueryUI Combobox not rendering "Select One..." option with empty value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Looking at the [example for a combobox](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) on jQuery UI it appears that the `Select One...` option is not available in the autocomplete list.

It looks like it is in the initial `<select>` statement but it is not available when viewing all options or if you start typing:

```
<select id="combobox" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
</select>
```

However, it looks like it does not appear in the generated `<ul>` list:

```
<ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front" style="display: none; top: 39px; left: 287.667px; width: 189px;">
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-89" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">ActionScript</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-90" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Asp</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-91" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">BASIC</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-92" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">C</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-93" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">C++</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-94" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Clojure</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-95" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">COBOL</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-96" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">ColdFusion</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-97" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Erlang</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-98" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Fortran</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-99" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Groovy</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-100" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Haskell</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-101" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Java</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-102" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">JavaScript</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-103" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Lisp</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-104" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Perl</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-105" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">PHP</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-106" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Python</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-107" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Ruby</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-108" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Scala</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-109" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Scheme</div></li>
</ul
```

Is there an elegant way to add the `Select One...` option to my jQuery-UI combobox without the need of having to set an arbitrary value?

Comment: This is managed under the custom `_source` function. You could ammend the `_renderMenu` and add it as a none selectable element into the menu that is auto selected, Or set a Placeholder value maybe.

Comment: Thank you @Twisty for your idea. I would still like the option to be selectable even though it may not contain a value. A placeholder might have worked too. For now, I modified the example source code. I posted my idea below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for jQueryUI's example I found the following section:

```
  _source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
    response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
      var text = $( this ).text();
      if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
        return {
          label: text,
          value: text,
          option: this
        };
    }) );
  },
```

Removing the check for `this.value` in the above if-statement will add the select list item which does not have a value set:

```
  _source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
    response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
      var text = $( this ).text();
      if ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) )
        return {
          label: text,
          value: text,
          option: this
        };
    }) );
  },
```